# Can I use SQLite libraries on google app engine?

Tags: sqlite, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm currently using Google Datastore for storing data. I want to keep an offline version in the form of sql database. Is it possible to use sqlite on google app engine to convert datastore into sql database?

Comment: are you referring to the usage of sqlite datastore stub for dev envirorment? or you are referring to a usecase like storing data from app engine in local like sqlite db of android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to use sqlite on AppEngine.

Currently there is no option to convert data from the AppEngine datastore to a SQL database.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this locally since Python Development Server v1.7.6 (link outdated)

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/old_devserver#Using_the_Datastore

> SQLite is now used as the backend for your local Datastore stub.
>   Running an app in the new Development Server for the first time will
>   automatically migrate any existing Datastore files into the SQLite
>   format.

New description from Google:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/devserver

> The development web server simulates the App Engine datastore using a SQLite-backed local datastore on your computer.

See also [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6411030/how-to-unpack-sqlite3-database-written-by-google-appengine-bulk-downloader).